# how can i improve my tor node measured bandwith?

Tags: networking, tor

I run a couple non-exit TOR nodes. One have a symmetric 50mbps, another have 10/50mbps. yet on both `nyx` shows measured bandwidth always under 500 bytes per second

`Bandwidth (limit: 12.0 MB/s, burst: 49.2 MB/s, measured: 460.0 B/s)`

Is this expected with the current state of the TOR network? They are both listed as "fast" by peers/atlas, but 460B/s sounds too low.